# File is used by another process after File.Copy Command

Tags: c#

i have to copy file from Source Folder to destination folder first.

then when ever user want to delete the file i have to delete it from the source location,

at that time this error occur while deleting " file is used by another process".

how can i make this file delete able?i used stream reader also but it was too slow to copy file so i don't need it.

Comment: Do you mean you give the user the option to delete it after copying it? if so you may be better to just move it instead of copying if they wish to "delete" the file

Comment: Sounds like the file is not closed after you copy it. If you post some code we can probably help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the file attribute to normal state, after the copy of file.
Eg -

```
 File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
 File.SetAttributes(destinationPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
```